# How is propene more reactive as well as more stable than ethene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, reactivity, hyperconjugation, nucleophilicity

I know that hyperconjugation stabilises a double bond. But in propene an electron-donating group $(\ce{-CH3})$ is increasing the electron density at the double bond, so its nucleophilicity should be higher. How can it be more stable as well as more reactive?

Comment: you said more reactive, but with what are you reacting both of them.

Comment: @TeslaBolt I meant that propene has higher nucleophilicity than ethene. I am reacting them both with the same electrophile.

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"?

Comment: @user55119 The more stable compound would start to disintegrate at a higher temperature.

Comment: By "stable"' do you mean the one that has the less positive (propene) heat of formation or possibly the one that reacts less rapidly with a particular electrophile? As to disintegration, I don't know what that process entails.

Comment: @user55119 The one that has less positive heat of formation. I think of the measure of what reacts less rapidly with a particular electrophile as their reactivity.

Comment: The heats of formation decreases by -5 kcal/mol for every -CH2- group that is added to each homologous. the n-alkanes . This doesn't mean that n-hexane is more stable tha n-pentane. [Look here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/thermo/heats-formation.html#Acyclic%20Alkanes).

Comment: @user55119 Then what do we mean when we say, "more substituted alkenes are more stable"? I have seen this statement in a lot of places.

Comment: I don't say that. Is benzene more stable than cyclohexene in the presence of bromine? Yes, it ia kinetic difference.  Is 1,2,4-tri-t-butylbenzene more stable than cyclohexene in in a UV photochemical reaction ? No, the benzene compound absorbs light to form a Dewar benzene and cyclohexene doesn't. Stability is relative to conditions..

Answer (score -1):

you need to go with the mechanism.

1st

[image]

in this case **propene will form a 2nd degree carbocation which is more stable.**

2nd
[image]

when the electrophile is having a lone pair then a 3 membered ring is formed as intermidiate.then the other Nucleophile attack to open the ring and thus product is formed.

you can refer to Markovnikov's Rule for further info(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markovnikov%27s_rule)